# Number Theory: Which numbers 101010...0101 are prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have this problem assigned for homework and I'm having some trouble with it. I'm in elementary number theory.

Set $M(k)=100^{k-1}+\dotsc +100+1$. Note that $M(k)$ has exactly $k$ ones.

For which $k$ is $M(k)$ a prime?

*Hint:* Set $R(k)=111\cdots 1$ with exactly $k$ ones and observe that $11\cdot M(k)=R(2k)=R(k)\cdot (10^k +1)$.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, have you shown that their observation is true?

Comment: observe that $M(k)$ is not a prime for any multiple of 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $k \geq 4$. Note that 11 divides exactly one of the factors on the right.
If $k$ is even, $M(k)=\frac{R(k)}{11} \times (10^k+1)$ has at least two factors; make a similar argument when $k$ is odd.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to how you found that $M(k)$ has at least two factors.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, thanks!

Comment: (+1) We don't need to worry about the parity of $k$ if we simply note that since $11\mid R(k)(10^k+1)$ and $11$ is prime, it must divide one or the other, so either $M(k)=\frac{R(k)}{11}(10^k+1)$ or $M(k)=R(k)\frac{10^k+1}{11}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Another hint:** I suppose the hint is trying to say something like if you "factor out" (deconvolve) "101" you will be getting $\sum_i 10^{4i}$. Does this make more sense?

---

Also you can look at the recursive relation $a_{n+1} = 1+100a_{n-1}$ ( which is one way to build the sequence ), how will it alter modulo $k$?

Fun curiosity, if we build the matrix $${\bf A} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\0&100\end{array}\right]$$ we can observe ${\bf A}^2 = \left[\begin{array}{rr}1&101\\0&10^4\end{array}\right] , {\bf A}^3 = \left[\begin{array}{rr}
1&10101\\0&10^6\end{array}\right]$ and so on. So this is a way to generate the sequence (upper right element).

Comment: Yes, perfect, it makes sense now! Thanks!

Comment: (+1) If there are an even number of $1$s, then there are two ways to divide things up: $$ \color{#F0C0C0}{0}\color{#C00000}{1}\color{#00A000}{01} \color{#C00000}{01}\color{#00A000}{01} \dots\color{#C00000}{01}\color{#00A000}{01} \color{#C00000}{01}\color{#00A000}{01} $$ which gives a factor of $101$ and $$ \color{#F0C0C0}{0}\color{#C00000}{1010101} \dots\color{#00A000}{01010101}$$ which gives a factor of $10^k+1$. Your suggestion seems to be along the line of the former, while the hint in the question seems to be along the line of the latter.

Answer (score 1):

**Big Hints:**

If $n$ is odd, then $10^n\equiv(-1)^n\equiv-1\pmod{11}$. Therefore, $11\mid10^n+1$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}100^k
&=\frac{100^n-1}{99}\\
&=\frac{10^n-1}{9}\frac{10^n+1}{11}
\end{align}
$$

---

If $n$ is even, then $n=2m$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}100^k
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1}100^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}100^{2k}(100+1)\\
&=101\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}100^{2k}\\
\end{align}
$$
Or we can start as we did when $n$ was odd,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}100^k
&=\frac{100^n-1}{99}\\
&=\frac{10^n-1}{99}(10^n+1)\\
&=\frac{100^m-1}{99}(10^n+1)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Yep those were big :)